# Custom Delegate for a custom View

Tags: ios, delegates, xamarin

I m using `Xamarin` for iOS and I have a custom `View` which inherit from `UIView`.
I would like to add a custom `delegate` to that view.

So far I found that:
[Delegate (not useful) example](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/delegates,_protocols,_and_events/)

I want my `delegate` to be on his own and won't inherit from any other known `delegate`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `delegate` property on `UIView` ([see Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/)). It does exists in some subclasses, like `UITextView` (and other types).

What you can do (beside using the base classes provided) is:

1. (with the unified API) create your own classes that implements the `IUITextViewDelegate` interface and assign it to the `Delegate` property;
2. Create any class that conforms to the delegate (i.e. minimally all required members), add the required `[Export]`, and assign it to the `WeakDelegate` property.

Comment: Thanks! U r the Man! Can I create any custom protocol and set a delegate? Any tutorial? Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: There's no need to thanks me, just upvote (for me) and mark as answered (for other future people with the same question). `WeakDelegate` can be set to any `NSObject` where the correct `[Export]` are present. That will work as long as you're following what ObjC requires (and you can follow Apple docs for such cases). In 98% of the case you'll prefer having a **strongly** typed version - for that you should use the `IMyProtocol` pattern (for a `MyProtocol` native protocol). That's much easier (e.g. code completion, complier checks) and you can then follow Xamarin documentation.